# Trim leading zero from Month/Day representation in Date String?

Tags: c#, string, oracle, date

In my Application I am attempting to fine-tune a Search function for users searching on Dates. Previously I did a straight `.ToUpper()` comparison between the entered Search Criteria and the DB Column. All Date values in my DB are saved with only the DATE itself (I strip out the unwanted Time using a CHECK constraint on the fields before INSERT/UPDATE).

Thus, values in my DB are saved (ex.) "7/1/2005", "6/14/2006", "10/1/2008". Because C# only has a DateTime datatype, it is necessary during my search to do some string manipulation to ensure the proper string is compared. For instance, the value [7/1/2005] in the DB will come through as "07/01/2005" after a `string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", o.DateFiled)`. Then since C# adds a default value of "12:00:00 AM" to any DateTime value without a Time specified, I as the Developer know this must be included for the Search to function properly on a Date field.

To make it simpler for users, I wanted them to be able to enter (ex.) "5/25/2013" or "05/25/2013" and get the same result, so I added a `TrimStart('0')` Maipulation:

```
// 7/1/2005 => 07/01/2005
m.DATE_FIELD.ToString().ToUpper() == searchCriteria.TrimStart('0').ToUpper()+" 12:00:00 AM"
```

This now successfully lets the user enter (ex.) "7/25/2013" or "07/25/2013", however if the value is (ex.) "7/1/2005" in the DB, this results in the search criteria being "7/01/2005 for the string comparison, which does not match up and causes the search to fail.

How can I trim both the leading 0 for the Month value and (if present) a leading zero for the Day value?

Comment: Use "Between" two dates from midnight one night to midnight the next night.

Comment: "it is necessary during my search to do some string manipulation" -- No, it's really not. You can compare `DateTime` values without any string comparisons. You can even just compare the `Date` part of those `DateTime` values if you have bogus time data in there.

Comment: Are your date values stored as strings in the db?

Comment: @hvd, I know I can compare `DateTime` values without the string comparison, but this particular function is an all-inclusive all field search so it is not always a date being searched against. @DaveZych, date values are stored as DATE in the DB.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic So make your all field search try to convert the string to a date. If the conversion succeeds, use the date value in the comparison with date fields. If the conversion fails, skip the date fields since you already know they can't match.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that user entered is valid date and you are validating that prior this comparison then you can simply use the following

```
m.DATE_FIELD.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(searchCriteria).Date
```

Comment: I cannot know what the user is searching for as it is an all field inclusive search (*) across everything.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `M` instead of `MM`, or `d` instead of `dd`, but honestly [hvd's comment in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549950/trim-leading-zero-from-month-day-representation-in-date-string#comment56842233_34549950) is correct - you should not be comparing strings.  You should convert from string input to a `DateTime`, then compare based on `DateTime` *which has no specific format of its own*.

Besides just the leading zero, also consider that date representation varies per locale (`d/M/yyyy` vs `M/d/yyyy` vs `yyyy-MM-dd`), and that only the `yyyy-MM-dd` format is sortable when in string form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the same thing Kishore suggested...  If so, please forgive.

That said, what if you parsed the user's text, and if it fails, then it's an automatic false, and if it succeeds then you can compare date to date:

```
DateTime searchDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(searchCriteria, out searchDate))
{
    if (m.DATE_FIELD.Date == searchDate.Date)
        // Do something amazing
}
```